# JavaScript, AngularJS, Meteor: class-like controller and helpers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, controller

I'm a Java EE developer and new to JS/AngularJS/Meteor. I read the most questions/answers including **class and helper** and no useful information for my questions.

I jumped into AngularJS and Meteor at the same time and without solid js knowledge.

When reading angularjs-based example of Meteor, I saw

```
class TodosListCtrl {
constructor($scope) {
$scope.viewModel(this);// cannot find explanation

this.helpers({
  tasks() {
    return Tasks.find({});
  }
})
}
}

...some lines skipped...
])
.component('todosList', {
templateUrl: 'imports/components/todosList/todosList.html',
controller: ['$scope', TodosListCtrl]
});
```

Q1: Clearly it declares a Controller by class-like method. But I cannot find some information about how to declare new 'object' this way and add variables/methods. Is this a JS level, angularjs level or meteor level thing?

Q2: I cannot find an explanation about **$scope.viewModel(this)** and I guess  it is like **$scope = this**, but why and how behind the scene?

Q3: the function **tasks()** inside the helper is called at startup of app, how may I put this method outside of the helper in order to control the calling time, like calling it by clicking a button?

Comment: When I started learning angularjs, reactjs or even jquery, I had a hard time understanding those frameworks/libraries because I didn't have any prior javascript knowledge. So, I learned javascript and then those frameworks started to make sense. So, I would advise you to have a fair amount of understanding of javascript before you dive into those amazing frameworks/libraries.

Comment: @paul-shuvo I agree with you and I would've done that if I have the time, but unfortunately I dont have the time to follow the js-angular-meteor path. That is why i need some guidence immediately.

Comment: The code above is specific to Meteor. There would be no `$scope.viewModel` or `this.helpers` in regular Angular app.